# Variance of the Mean

Tags: probability, variance

Hi I've a question that may seem very basic or may be breaking some math so sorry if i am, just couldn't find the answer online.

$Var(\mu) = E(\mu^2)-E(\mu)^2$

$Var(\mu) = \mu^2 - \mu^2$

$Var(\mu) = 0$

Thanks for any help or clarification.

Comment: You can take the variance of a random variable. What does the variance of a real number mean? (or it's expectation, for that matter). If it means the variance of the constant random variable  which takes the value $\mu$, then the above calculation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not finding the variance of a number ($\mu$) unless of course your distribution is constant. Variance is defined as the sum of the squares from the mean or $\sum\limits_{i\in S}(x_i-\mu)^2f(x)=E(x^2)-E(x)$ You are correct in saying that $E(\mu^2)$ is constant and $\mu^2,$ however it does not make any sense for you to calculate like that, you do not find expected value and variances of constants, even if your function was constant, $E(x^2)$ would still equal that constant and not the constant squared. The variance of a constant distribution would obviously be 0.

Comment: Thank you, being honest i actually forgot that the var of a constant is 0